# Iinvalid operands of types

Tags: c++

Let be

gf.h

```
typedef unsigned short gf_t;
class GaloisField{
public:
 gf_t * gf_exp;
 gf_t * gf_log;
 int gf_extension_degree, gf_cardinality, gf_multiplicative_order;
 static gf_t gf_ord();
 static int gf_inv(int x);
```

gf.cpp

```
 gf_t GaloisField::gf_ord(){
   return gf_multiplicative_order;
 }

 int GaloisField::gf_inv(int x){
   return gf_exp[GaloisField::gf_ord() - gf_log[x]]; //line 181
 }
```

I get the message:
gf.cpp:181: error: invalid operands of types ‘gf_t’ and ‘gf_t ()(gf_t)’ to binary ‘operator-’. Why this?

Answer (score 5):

Since `gf_inv` is a static function, there is no `this` pointer. Without `this`, you can't access `gf_log`.

I don't know why the error message is so cryptic.

Comment: I bet `gf_log` is also a function somewhere. We don't have a complete testcase here.

Comment: @moswald How I will be ale to access?

Comment: Get rid of the `static` keyword, and fix up the use cases to use an object, not the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues in your code:

- you define `gf_ord` as `static`, and it cannot be, since it returns an instance field. You probably mean `const` instead,
- same for `gf_inv`
- `gf_ord` returns a `gf_t`, but the internal field is a int, you could get rounding errors

Here's perhaps a better declaration:

```
#include <exception>


class GaloisField{
protected:
    gf_t * gf_exp;
    gf_t * gf_log;
    int gf_extension_degree, gf_cardinality;
    gf_t gf_multiplicative_order;
public:
    GaloisField();
    gf_t gf_ord() const;
    int gf_inv(int x) throw(std::runtime_error);
    // ...
};
```

and in gf.cpp

```
GaloisField::GaloisField() {
    // here you should initialize your protected fields to default values
    // and create the gf_exp and gf_log arrays
}

gf_t GaloisField::gf_ord() const {
    return gf_multiplicative_order;
}

int GaloisField::gf_inv(int x) {
     int idx = gf_ord() - gf_log[x];
     if (idx >= 0)
       return gf_exp[idx];
     throw std::runtime_error("gf_inv");
}
```

If you don't initialize the arrays in your class, you will get runtime errors, notably at line 181.

Perhaps you will also need another constructor to give your internal fields proper values.

Comment: @Juan: Then you haven't presented us with a complete testcase, and there is something you hid from us that is causing a problem.